# no message available in the queue of RabbitMQ with Spring RabbitMQ of Apache camel

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, apache-camel, queue, spring-rabbit

when I try to publish a message from a queue to another queue using Spring RabbitMQ of the Apache camel component the destination queue doesn't get any message.

```
@Component
public class WeatherRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        fromF(RABBIT_URI,"weather","weather")
       .toF(RABBIT_URI,"weather_event","weather_event")
 }
}
```

and this is my config component :

```
@Configuration
public class CamelConfiguration {
    public static final String RABBIT_URI="spring-rabbitmq:amq.direct?exchangeType=direct&queues=%s&routingKey=%s";

    @Bean 
    // auto injected because we name it with rabbitConnectionFactory
    public ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory() {
       //define a connectionFactory
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        factory.setPort(5672);
        factory.setUsername("guest");
        factory.setPassword("guest");
        return factory;
    }

}
```

I have created manually the two queues using the RabbitMQ interface but he problem is still present

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like there is a `queues` param for that kind of Apache Camel URI for RabbitMQ: https://camel.apache.org/components/3.21.x/rabbitmq-component.html.

I would suggest to use different URIs: for consumer side based on `queue` and for producer based on `routingKey`. That's how AMQP protocol works.

Comment: With spring rabbitMQ'component  of Apache camel; routingKey is allowed for both prodcuer and consumer but queue is not available in both! only queues is available and only for consumer!

Comment: Sure! I'm not OK with Apache Camel and can just remove my answer: I just judge from whatever I see in their docs. Even if the `routingKey` is available for both consumer and producer it does not make sense for consumer. The `exchangeName` and `routingKey` is a pair for producer. The consumer needs only `queue`. We might look into different Apache Camel version, but I fail to see `queues` in the docs.